# Driver manager set, or java code to connect from CentOS 6.8

Tags: marklogic

We are trying to make a connection from our IBM DataStage environment (running on Centos 6.8(Final)) to a MarkLogic environment.
We have tried using the ODBC drivers available from the MarkLogic Developer Community (https://developer.marklogic.com/products/odbc) without any success.
Has anyone done something similar with success? Looking for a driver manager set or Java code to make this connection work. Any documentation or guidance  is appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/JDBC

Comment: Are you looking to ingest data into MarkLogic or to get data out, or both? In either case, could you use MarkLogic's REST interface to get the job done?